# Obtain Particle Collision Force from particle collison

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system

I am trying to obtain the force involved in a particle collision using:

OnParticleCollision(GameObject other)

This [Particle Collision Events on the documentation](https://docs.huihoo.com/unity/5.4/Documentation/en/ScriptReference/ParticleCollisionEvent.html)

looks like what I would need however I cannot access .velocity, .normal, .intersection, or .colliderComponent[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRMBX.png)

Is there a library or something missing from my code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get force. Because as long as I know unity particles doesn't have a mass. So F=m*a can't be calculated.

But what you can get is a velocity at which they hit the collider. Try reading [OnParticleCollision](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnParticleCollision.html) and [Particle Collision Event](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleCollisionEvent.html)